# Bitbucket/SourceTree Issue > Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree and trying to push some changes I've made to a file. I have a BitBucket account connected to SourceTree. When I go to push the changes, everything usually works fine, but today I ran into an issue. I receive the following error (repeated multiple times like this too).

[image: Sourcetree error message]

```
git --no-optional-locks -c color.branch=false -c color.diff=false -c color.status=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master 
Pushing to bitbucket.org:<username>/<folder>
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pushing to bitbucket.org:<username>/<folder>
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pushing to bitbucket.org:<username>/<folder>
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Pushing to bitbucket.org:<username>/<folder>
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Completed with errors, see above
```

I removed the username and folder/pathway for privacy reasons. So far, my attempts to resolve this error have been to create a new ssh key using the terminal, as described in [this article](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/) under the heading "Set up SSH on macOS/Linux." I made sure I added this new key to my profile settings in BitBucket, not my repository settings, but it's still showing the same error. I've also tried disconnecting my BitBucket account in Sourcetree, quitting the program, and then reconnecting my account, but no luck.

Is there anything else I can try to resolve this? I am unfamiliar with using command line, so I might need more explanation if that is part of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

> I made sure I added this new key to my profile settings in BitBucket, not my repository settings

Actually, you also need to register your private key to your SourceTree configuration, as [shown here](https://newbedev.com/sourcetree-on-windows-how-to-connect-to-ssh) (for Windows, but the same idea applies to Linux):

> `Tools > Options > General > SSH Client Configuration`, I had to point it to the `id_rsa` key, and select OpenSSH as the SSH Client
>
> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fGKy.png]

The OP suggests "[Set up an SSH key](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-an-ssh-key/)" for the official documentation.